# Git: synch a branch with the original forked master

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-fork

I forked a GitHub project into my own repository. My repository contains only a "master" branch in which I commit my own code. The forked project contains a "master" branch only as well.

From time to time, I find and fix some bug in the original code and I want to create a pull request so that the developers of the original project can add the fix. However, I don't want to add to this pull request all the code I changed, just the fix.

I think the correct way to proceed here is to create a new branch in my repository, synchronize this with the original forked master, commit the fix and create the pull request. My question is: how can I create a branch and get rid of all my commits to synchronize it with the forked master?

As an aside, is this actually the most practical way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest next steps for solving your problem:

1. configure **remote** address to the forked master

`git remote add upstream <url_to_forked_project>;`

2. fetch all changes from upstream

`git fetch upstream;`

3. create new **fix** branch and download forked master

`git checkout upstream/master -b fix;`

4. apply you fixes

`git cherry-pick <commit_hash>;` or make a new commit somehow

5. push your changes to your remote github repository

`git push origin fix:fix;`

`git branch -d fix;` - remove the unused branch

6. and after that you can create a new pull request from your remote **fix** branch

Comment: Thanks, it worked. What is the difference between `fix:fix` and `fix` in step 5?

Comment: it's more complex syntax when you need to define another name for remote branch. You can read this article for additional information 'how works PUSH command' https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/

Answer (score 2):

You can create a branch and revert all the commits using [git revert](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) command that you want to get rid of.

And then [sync forked repository](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/) to get all the changes done in the upstream repository.